# Sqlite database connection is closing on me

Tags: java, sqlite, database-connection

I have a database adapter in my web service that when created, opens a connection to a Sqlite database:

```
public DatabaseAdapterJava(Database database)
{           
   try 
   {
      exceptionController = new ExceptionControllerJava();

      // establish a connection to the database
      Class.forName(database.getDatabaseClass());
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database.getDatabasePath());
      conn.setAutoCommit(true);
   }
   catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
   {
      exceptionController.logException(this.toString(), "DatabaseAdapterSqlite", e.getMessage(), false);
   }
   catch(SQLException e)
   {
      exceptionController.logException(this.toString(), "DatabaseAdapterSqlite", e.getMessage(), false);
   }                
}
```

This works wonderful, or at least it did.  Recently however I started getting null connection exceptions on calls to the database after the second one.

For example:

```
int user_id = dbadapter.createUser(user);

//do something...

int user_records_affected = dbadapter.updateUser(user);
```

Then when the next statement to the database is executed the connection is closed:

```
int other_id = dbadapter.createLogRecord(log);
```

It appears that the database connection is closing on me without my explicit consent.

What might I be doing to cause the connection to close?

The create and update methods simply assemble a string sql statement which gets passed to:

```
@Override
public boolean executeSQL(String sql) {

    try{

        cm = conn.createStatement();
        cm.execute(sql);            

        return true;                    

    }catch(SQLException e){
        ExceptionMessage = "SQLException: "+e.getMessage();
        return false;
    }catch(Exception e){
        **ExceptionMessage = "Exception: "+e.getMessage();**
        return false;
    }


}
```

I have highlighted the exception path which returns:

> ExceptionMessage = Exception: Null

Comment: Yes. Exception thrown is 'Null.'  No more or less.

Comment: Can you tell us what object is null?

Comment: Hard to say what's happening without seeing the createUser and updateUser methods.

Comment: It's not a null point exeception, the actual error message = Null.  As my question states, I only open the connection when creating the adapter and close it when I destroy it.

Comment: Do a `e.printStackTrace()` instead. Or run through it with a debugger and check if something is `null`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I did a stack trace and it only appears that the connection object is returning a null at conn.createStatement(); I am not certain how to proceed with this.  The connection object itself appears to not be null.  PERHAPS IT'S A TIMING ISSUE?

Comment: @AndroidAddict The javadoc for `createStatement()` says `returns a new default Statement object` so I don't think you can get `null` returned. Add an `if (conn==null)` somewhere before that, but as you said, I don't know how that would be true if you don't reassign it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, checking for null and reopening the connection certainly does fix the problem.  But, it still does not tell me why it's closing in the first place.  Any thoughts there?  I have verified that no where do I explicitly close the connection until the end of my method that is performing all these actions.

Comment: @AndroidAddict When you say close, do you mean that somewhere `close()` was called on it, or the variable is being set to `null`? The actual database connection can be closed from the database side for whatever reason (resources, timeout, etc.).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, in this case I just mean that for whatever reason the connection is no longer available for use, closed, set to null or otherwise.  Curious that this all worked a couple of days ago.  Today, I started full integration testing and this cropped up.  I did partial integration testing on Friday of last week and this part worked fine.  No changes have been made - comparing source, but all of a sudden when I expanded the integration testing to include other things, well you get the picture.  Perhaps it's a resource issue.  Thanks for the feedback - it's REALLY APPRECIATED.